# How do I toggle boolean field

Tags: python, django

I am working on a project where user have his own profile, I want to create a BooleanField on model so that user can set profile privacy, private or public. I have added a BooleanField to modal (is_private). Also i have a toggle switch on template but i do not know how to go with it with Django. I want when a user click on switch boolean field is true (private), when user click again on switch boolean field is false (public). Jquery maybe needed as well.

[image]

Model:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True,null=True) 
    is_private = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Views:

```
def profile_edit_view(request):
    p = Profile.objects.filter(user=request.user).order_by('-id')
    context = {'p':p}
    return render(request, 'profile_edit.html', context)
```

urls:

```
path('account/edit/', profile_edit_view, name ='profile-edit'),
```

Profile Edit Template:

```
<form method="POST" name="is_private">
 {% csrf_token %}
<div class="custom-control custom-switch">
 <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customSwitches" name="is_private">
 <label class="custom-control-label" for="customSwitches">Private Account</label>
 </div>
 </form>
<p class="text-muted font-weight-normal font-small">
  When your account is private, only people you approve can see your photos and videows on Pixmate. Your existing followers won't be affected.
</p>
```

Comment: name attribute is missing for input field `name="is_private"` If you are working with ModalForm else the corresponding name given in Form class should be given

Comment: @AchuthVarghese... Thanks for that insight. Can you help me out with views.py? I did not find any tutorial on how to toggle boolean field in Django

Comment: What is the need of order_by in your views function? There would be only one Profile corresponding to an User right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. In template file change the input tag as shown

```html
<!-- Mark the checkbox as checked or not by is_private -->
<input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customSwitches" {% if p.is_private %}checked{% endif %}>
```

In that same template file add this script

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // send request to change the is_private state on customSwitches toggle
        $("#customSwitches").on("change", function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: "{% url 'change_privacy' %}",
                data: {
                    csrfmiddlewaretoken: "{{ csrf_token }}",
                    is_private: this.checked // true if checked else false
                },
                type: "POST",
                dataType : "json",
            })
            // $.ajax().done(), $.ajax().fail(), $ajax().always() are upto you. Add/change accordingly
            .done(function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                // show some message according to the response. 
                // For eg. A message box showing that the status has been changed
            })
            .always(function() {
                console.log('[Done]');
            })
        })
    });
</script>
```

2. Add a new path in your urls file of the app which binds to a view. Say: a function named `change_privacy()` in your views

```py
path('changeprivacy', change_privacy, name="change_privacy"),
```

3. In views file add a new function. You need to import JsonResponse

```py
from django.http import JsonResponse

def change_privacy(request):
    if request.is_ajax() and request.method=='POST':

        profile = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)

        profile.is_private = True if request.POST.get('is_private') == 'true' else False
        profile.save()
        data = {'status':'success', 'is_private':profile.is_private}
        return JsonResponse(data, status=200)
    else:
        data = {'status':'error'}
        return JsonResponse(data, status=400)
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: @MrHize okay. Please clear me on this. Are you trying to  save when you toggle the switch OR are you submitting a form after you toggle this switch ?

Comment: I want to save state on toggle. I want boolean field default False (public profile), so when user toggle boolean field turns True (private profile).

Comment: Thanks for your answers, but the code is just too much and not arranged, i have tried this but not working the way i want it. I was able to make boolean field true or false in admin. I do not want that, i want to make boolean true or false on frontend when clicked on. Please make your code clearly, just make it simple in one way. Thanks

Comment: @MrHize then you need to work on only the Ajax part and the new function change_privacy

Comment: @MrHize in the view which shows this privacy toggle you need to pass the is_privacy to the template and uncheck or check the toggle. In that template file add Ajax. For the status to change when you toggle the switch, you need to send a request through ajax

Comment: I understand what you mean, but i do not have an idea on how to go on with it. Can you make a clearer answer to my question? Create a new Modal, Views, Ajax. With this i can easily understand your logic. Thanks

Comment: @MrHize you have a view with which this template with the toggle is rendered. Can you share that code in your question please

Comment: Please can you make your answer clear? There are too many ways you code, just make it clear. Model, views, template.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to do it with Ajax.

First include jQuery:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Ajax setup, you need to include a CSRF token (or make decorate your view with [`@csrf_exempt`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/csrf/#django.views.decorators.csrf.csrf_exempt)). Relevant section in the [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/csrf/#ajax). If you don't include the CSRF token in your request you will get `403 Forbidden`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getCookie(name) {
        let cookieValue = null;
        if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
            const cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
            for (let i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                const cookie = cookies[i].trim();
                // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
                if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                    cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return cookieValue;
    }

    const csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
</script>
```

Then make the Ajax request:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("document").ready(function () {
        $("#customSwitches").change(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                headers: {
                    "X-CSRFToken": csrftoken
                },
                url: {% url 'privacy' %},
                data: {
                    "enabled": this.checked,
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                },
                error: function (data, msg) {
                    console.log("ERROR", data, msg);
                }
            });
        })
    });
</script>
```

Adjust the url to work with your project and don't forget to include the CSRF token in the header.

Then you can get the value of the checkbox in your view and update the value for your user:

```
def privacy_view(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        enabled = request.POST["enabled"]
        profile = Profile.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user)
        profile.is_private = enabled
        profile.save()
    return render(request, "privacy.html")
```